# NetLogo computing beta distribution/function

Tags: netlogo

I am using the stats extension in NetLogo to compute a beta function:

`set z (stats:beta (H + 1) (T + 1))`

Where H and T are numbers of heads and tails in a coin flip. 
The use of the stats extension is not essential, I have the same problem when using the factorial expression of the beta function.

The problem is that when `H + T > 168`, NetLogo reports `z = 0` and there are some procedures I cannot perform [in particular, the beta distribution]

Is there any way to approximate the beta function (or distribution) in Netlogo such that it does not run into this problem?

Comment: if you don't get any joy here, you could try asking the question in the stats forums(in a slightly different way to focus on the approximation aspect rather than NetLogo) . They are probably in a better position to provide advice about alternative calculation approaches.

Comment: Thanks JenB, I'll do that after a couple of days if I don't get a reply. 
Actually, I think that the central problem is that NetLogo is incapable of computing numbers greater than zero and smaller than -aprox- 2 E-51. It just reports zero for those values.

Comment: Note that NetLogo uses IEEE 754 double precision floating point, the same floating point standard that most programming languages follow, so your problem here isn't really NetLogo-specific, I don't think.

Comment: P.S. I don't think 2E-51 is the right bound; IEEE 754 goes down to 4.9E-324.

Comment: I think the problem is computing large factorials. The denominator of the beta function B(H,T) is factorial(H+T-1).
But if H+T-1 > 170, then we have something > E325.
In fact when I try to compute factorial(171) Netlogo reports "Infinity".

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to solve my own question. I hope this is helpful for other people too.
The main problem is to compute large factorials - as it came up in the comments. In particular, 171! is simply too largo to compute. So the optimal solution would be to minimize the need of computing such numbers.

For the discrete case, the beta function is the following:

B(alpha,beta) = (alpha - 1)!(beta - 1)! / (alpha + beta - 1)!

The mistake was to try to compute first nominator, then denominator, and then divide; because denominator gets too large. I found two solutions, one of them is better than the other but much more complicated - but actually I think it is close to optimal.

The less optimal but shorter is based on the idea of simplifying the denominator using the largest nominator:

```
to-report betafunc [alpha beta]
  ifelse (alpha >= beta)
  [let v1 (factorial (beta - 1) (0))
   let v2 (factorial (alpha + beta - 1) (alpha - 1))
   report (v1 / v2)]
  [let v1 (factorial (alpha - 1) (0))
   let v2 (factorial (alpha + beta - 1) (beta - 1))
  report (v1 / v2)]
end
```

where

```
to-report factorial [n m]
 if (n = m) [report 1]
 report (n * factorial (n - 1) (m))
end
```

The problem with this one is that denominator still grows very fast. The idea for the second solution is to proceed by simplifying each step of the factorial.

For example, if we have (5!8!)/(12)! we can express it as the product of
(5.8/12).(4.7/11).(3.6/10) ... (1.4/8).(1.3/7)...(1.1/5)(1.1/4)...(1.1/1)

By stepwise simplifying each term of the sequence we make sure that things do not grow up that fast. Here is my solution:

```
to-report stepwisefactorial3 [n1 n2 d]
  if (n1 = 0) [report stepwisefactorial2 (n2) (d)]
  if (n2 = 0) [report stepwisefactorial2 (n1) (d)]
  if (d = 0)  [report (stepwisefactorial1 (n1) * stepwisefactorial1 (n2))]
  report ((((n1 * n2) / d)) * stepwisefactorial3 (n1 - 1) (n2 - 1) (d - 1))
end

to-report stepwisefactorial2 [n d]
  if (n = 0) [report (1 / (stepwisefactorial1 (d)))]
  if (d = 0) [report stepwisefactorial1 (n)]
  report ((n / d)* stepwisefactorial2 (n - 1) (d - 1))
end

to-report stepwisefactorial1 [d]
  if d = 0 [ report 1 ]
  report d * stepwisefactorial1 (d - 1)
end
```

Still things blow up if alpha + beta > 345; but it is progress.

Comment: nice functions. See http://sl8r000.github.io/ab_testing_statistics//use_the_beta_distribution/ for discussion. From http://www.vosesoftware.com/ModelRiskHelp/index.htm#Distributions/Approximating_one_distribution_with_another/Normal_approximation_to_the_Beta_distribution.htm the normal approximation is okay for most of the cases you care about. You could test if both A,B > 50, then the normal approximation for A near B and the factorial simplification approach if they are too different. Note that different A,B is when there is more cancelling out anyway, so smaller simplified.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for leaving this for future searchers.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Chris' answer, the **stats extension** does have a log of Gamma function, **stats:loggamma**.  It handles an argument of considerably over 171 and thus a and b can add to well over 172 as well.

```
observer> show stats:beta 85 86
observer: 1.2864854397253604E-52
observer> show exp (stats:loggamma 85 + stats:loggamma 86 - stats:loggamma (85 + 86))
observer: 1.2864854397251408E-52
observer> show stats:beta 86 86
observer: 0
observer> show exp (stats:loggamma 86 + stats:loggamma 86 - stats:loggamma (86 + 86))
observer: 6.394810665301235E-53
observer> show exp (stats:loggamma 200 + stats:loggamma 200 - stats:loggamma (200 + 200))
observer: 9.713217247613997E-122
```

A new version of the stats extension (v1.4.0) has been posted with a "bigBeta" function that uses the logs.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a side comment, but the question was already answered, anyway.)

I wondered about using logs.

```
Beta(x,y) = Gamma(x) * Gamma(y) / Gamma(x + y)
= exp ( ln(Gamma(x)) + ln(Gamma(y)) - ln(Gamma(x + y)) )
```

Playing with that a bit shows that the Stats extension is smart enough to calculate Beta this way, and what it really comes down to is the **overflow** in Gamma.

```
observer> show stats:gamma 171
observer: 7.257415615308E306
observer> show stats:gamma 172
observer: Infinity
```

(I cribbed here
http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/calculating-beta-function/ .)